# In Shopify Empire Theme Im Facing This Header Problem

Tags: css, header, shopify, width, shopify-template

I Want To Make It Fully Stretched And Look Like Normal Header Menu Please Some One Help Me To fix This Issue! now it looks broken it placed in left side and ugly.
I Shared The Image Of That Issue
Problem was solved by me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the codes of the menu part at least. But I guess it's the width property issue of your menu bar CSS codes.
Try to add `width: 100%;` in the root container of your menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Edit CSS file, I think there was an error for this issue.